# Send Client side variable to Server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

There seem to be something like this but in the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011538/how-to-send-a-variable-from-server-to-client-in-meteor). This is [closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630829/meteor-pass-data-from-client-to-server) but I'm not storing anything.

I am only using stripe for a charge in my other [post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705247/how-to-charge-a-stripe-card-in-meteor/):

**Client:**

I am grabbing the value, with jQuery, from an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"/>
var amount = $("#amount").val() *100; // the js client
```

Server:

To charge the card, you would have something like:

```
amount: 7000, // I want to remove the static value
```

I need something like this:

```
amount: amount
```

I am still learning js and I thought jquery would work but I guess not. I've tried passing `amount` into the `isServer` function but that does not work. Any alternatives?

I have also tried to use `var amount = document.getElementById('#amount');` But `document` is not defined.

Edit:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'chargeCard': function(stripeToken, amount) {
      check(stripeToken, Object);
      var stripe = Meteor.npmRequire('stripe')('sk_test_rand');

      stripe.customers.create({
        email: 'a@aol.com'
      }).then(function() {
        return stripe.charges.create({
          amount: amount,
          currency: 'gbp',
          source: stripeToken.id
        });
      }).then(function(err, charge) {
        // New charge created on a new customer
        console.log(err, charge);
      }, function(err) {
        // Deal with an error
        console.log('Card not charge')
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: any particular errors? Could you please give full jquery code where you are calling isServer function. It will be great if you could also mention the server side code.

Comment: @Sylar http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods `meteor methods`

Comment: I have edited the post. @MarkUretsky I'll have a read. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylar do you have a meteor call at the client? `Meteor.call('chargeCard', token, amount, function(err, res) { }`

Comment: @MarkUretsky No. But just added amount to the cal()l and it worked. You can add that as the answer and ill accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sylar glad it helped! :) I did thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a meteor method on the server from the client you need to use `meteor.call`:

```
Meteor.call('chargeCard', token, amount, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  // success
  // if you return anything from the server you can find it with res
  console.log(res);
});
```